# Scrollup not working in StickyListviewHeader with SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I am using `StickyHeaderListview` in my project to display contents and for refreshing the list, I am using `SwipeRefreshLayout`.
The problem here is, when I try to scroll up the list, it starts refreshing the list and not allowing to view the previous items of list.

I want the behavior should be such as the list get refresh only when I've reached to the first item and I try to scroll up , not everytime when i scroll up the list.

Can anyone help on this?

P.s. For implementing SwipeRefreshLayout, I am refering [this example](http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/)

Comment: You are probably adding more than one View to your SwipeRefreshLayout. 

The following is stated in the reference regarding SwipeRefreshLayout:

This layout should be made the parent of the view that will be
refreshed as a result of the gesture and can only support one direct
child.

Comment: @user1281750 I've added a `FrameLayout` inside the `SwipeRefreshLayout` which contains the `StickyHeadersList` and an empty view.

Answer (score 18):

I faced the same problem when using `StickyHeaderListview` as a direct child of `SwipeRefreshLayout`. `StickyHeaderListview` is in fact a `FrameLayout` wrapping a `ListView` inside. As **nitesh goel** explained, this would lead to problems with `canChildScrollUp()`. Based on **nitesh goel**'s example, this is a full version of `CustomSwipeRefreshLayout` that works well for me:

```
public class CustomSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

    /**
     * A StickyListHeadersListView whose parent view is this SwipeRefreshLayout
     */
    private StickyListHeadersListView mStickyListHeadersListView;

    public CustomSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setStickyListHeadersListView(StickyListHeadersListView stickyListHeadersListView) {
        mStickyListHeadersListView = stickyListHeadersListView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
        if (mStickyListHeadersListView != null) {
            // In order to scroll a StickyListHeadersListView up:
            // Firstly, the wrapped ListView must have at least one item
            return (mStickyListHeadersListView.getListChildCount() > 0) &&
                    // And then, the first visible item must not be the first item
                    ((mStickyListHeadersListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0) ||
                            // If the first visible item is the first item,
                            // (we've reached the first item)
                            // make sure that its top must not cross over the padding top of the wrapped ListView
                            (mStickyListHeadersListView.getListChildAt(0).getTop() < 0));

            // If the wrapped ListView is empty or,
            // the first item is located below the padding top of the wrapped ListView,
            // we can allow performing refreshing now
        } else {
            // Fall back to default implementation
            return super.canChildScrollUp();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I wanted to mention to future googlers that this also works if you are using any kind of AdapterView child as your custom list view etc.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I have got it working. If the `SwipeRefreshLayout` is the root of the layout and the `ListView` resides deep into the hierarchy (I had put the `ListView` inside a `RelativeLayout` along with the empty `TextView`) and not the direct child of the `SwipeRefreshLayout`, it won’t detect a swipe up on the list view properly.

You should create a custom class that extends `SwipeRefreshLayout` and override `canChildScrollUp()` method in `SwipRefreshLayout`

Here is a example :

```
public class CustomSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout{
    private AbsListView view;

    public CustomSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setView(AbsListView view){
        this.view=view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
        return view.getFirstVisiblePosition()!=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar problem, the direct child should be an instance of ScrollView (or ListView). The SwipeRefreshLayout will only take in account the direct child's scroll and not the child's of that direct child. I managed to solve this by using two SwipeRefreshLayouts.

I posted the code on [github](https://github.com/AndroidExamples/SwipeRefreshLayout-ListViewExample).

Comment: Thank you for responding.I'll surely try this solution. +1 for help attempt.

Comment: @User22791 please tell ping i need some help from you reagarding swiperefreshlayout.

Comment: @User22791 thanks for swift response. please follow the below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236650/swiperefreshlayout-in-android

Comment: @User22791 please have a look on the above link.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i think i made something for a generally use :

```
public class CustomSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
    private View v;

    public CustomSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setView(View v) {
        this.v = v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
        return this.v.canScrollVertically(-1);
    }
}
```

With that solution, only set the view you want to scroll inside the SwipeRefreshLayout, after call canChildScrollUp(). like this :

```
this.refreshLayout.setView(aView);
this.refreshLayout.canChildScrollUp();
```

I don't test it a lot, but if i'm right it will work for every view at every place (direct child or not) in the SwipeRefreshLayout.

(for me it was SwipeRefreshLayout => RelativeLayout => SrcollView => linearLayout)

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple solution:

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {                                                   
    @Override                                                                                                   
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {                                       
    }                                                                                                           

    @Override                                                                                                   
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {    
        int topRowVerticalPosition = (list == null || list.getChildCount() == 0) ?                              
                0 : list.getChildAt(0).getTop();                                                                
        swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled((topRowVerticalPosition >= 0));                                           
    }                                                                                                           
});
```

So, if you're on the top of the listview you will be enabled to do refresh.